# Flutter Sqlite , select one result from database table

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I'd like know , isn't possible to select just one row from database using Flutter and Sqlite ?

I have tried this code :

```
// db.dart
Future<dynamic> find(Note note) async {
   await openDb();
   return await _database.query('note', where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [note.id], limit: 1);
}

// detail.dart
// note is an object
final noteO = dbmanager.find(note);
print(noteO);
```

**the output** of print(noteO) in console is :

```
I/flutter ( 8845): Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `final noteO = dbmanager.find(note);` give you a `Future<dynamic>`.

If you want to get the result of your query, you need to put the `await` keyword :

```
final noteO = await dbmanager.find(note);
```